# OS X: How to execute bash command when you launch some program?

Tags: macos, bash

For example, I want to open Chrome and execute some bash command by clicking on Chrome icon or by launching Chrome through Spotlight. How can I do that?

It was simple in Windows where I could right-click on a program's icon and write terminal command or some command line options.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to execute a bash command on Mac OS is via /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app.

You can create a script using a text editor which Terminal.app will then execute for you.

So the obvious way to achieve something similar to what I think you want would be to use (say) /Applications/Textedit.app to write a file containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
[whatever commands you like]
open /Applications/Chrome.app
```

then save it as – say – "bashChrome.command" (without the quotes).

You then need to make the file executable using the command `chmod u+x`.

The easy way is to type "chmod u+x " (without the quotes) into Terminal.app, drag and drop bashChrome.command into the Terminal window, then hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Then, any time you double-click the file bashChrome.command, Terminal will launch and run a script which will execute your bash commands then launch Chrome for you.